# Passing data between two forms

Tags: c#, forms, properties

first of all i want you to know that i know that there a lot of results for this question, but i have searched far and wide still haven't come up with a solution for my problem.

i have tried to do the following:

```
1.constructor

2.objects

3.properties

4.delegates
```

but none of my implementation of them really did worked as wanted (in this "solution" i have used properties

when i press "back" on the "pop up" screen i dont in the main screen the value i choose from in the "pop up" screen

basically, it's something like, i have  main screen and a "pop up"

```
the main screen

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BakaritCV
{
    public partial class FrmProdChoose : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        CVFeedUtilities utilities = new CVFeedUtilities();
        Mixtures mixture;
        public string selectedDefault = " 102";

        string t;
        public FrmProdChoose(string t)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.t = t;

        }
        public FrmProdChoose()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmMain frmload = new FrmMain();
            utilities.moveBetweenScreens(this, frmload);
        }

        private void mixtureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            utilities.loadPopUp(this, mixture);
        }

        private void FrmProdChoose_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mixture = new Mixtures(this);
            mixtureBtn.Text = selectedDefault;

        }
        public string Selected
        { 
            get { return selectedDefault; }
            set { selectedDefault = value;  }

        }




    }
}
```

the "pop up"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BakaritCV
{
    public partial class Mixtures : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm     
    {
        string[] mixture = new string[] { "102", "103", "104", "105" };
        MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTile[] tiles;
        FrmProdChoose form;     
        string  selectedDefault; 
        CVFeedUtilities utilities = new CVFeedUtilities();
        public Mixtures(FrmProdChoose form)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.form = form;
        }

        private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form.Selected = selectedDefault;
            utilities.closePopUp(this, form);
        }

        private void Mixtures_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tiles = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTile[] { tileOne, tileTwo, tileThree, tileFour};
            for (int i = 0; i < mixture.Length; i++)
                tiles[i].Text = mixture[i];
        }

        private void tileOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tileOne.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            removeBackColor(1); 
        }

        private void tileTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tileTwo.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            removeBackColor(2); 
        }

        private void tileThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tileThree.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            removeBackColor(3); 
        }

        private void tileFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tileFour.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            removeBackColor(4); 
        }

        private void tileFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tileFive.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            removeBackColor(5); 
        }


        public void removeBackColor(int index)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == index - 1)
                {
                    selectedDefault = tiles[i].Text;                    
                    continue;
                }

                else tiles[i].BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

and the functions `loadPopUp` and `closePopUp`

```
   public void loadPopUp(Form from, Form to)
        {
            to.Tag = from;
            to.Show(from);
        }
        public void closePopUp(Form from, Form to)
        {
            to.Tag = from;
            if (!to.Visible)
                to.Show(from);
            from.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please describe your problem? What do you want to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: added the question

Comment: You are setting `selectedDefault` property of main form before closing the popup. Are you not getting property value updated in main form? Is it throwing error? Are you getting unexpected value in the property? Also you should not use variable ? You have public property `Selected` you should be using that to get or set value from outside.

Comment: Where should the picked value be displayed? As Text of the `mixtureBtn` (which I guess is a button)?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the value `selectedDefault` is getting the right value at the pop up screen, but it aint getting passed to the main screen via the `Selected prop` in the main screen, also the value should be pressed upon pressing the

Comment: @meica the 'mixtureBtn' is a button whcih pop up the "pop up" window

Comment: Are you sure that the value isn't passed? For me it looks like that the main screen simply isn't updated with the new value. Therefore my question: Where should the new value be displayed and how do you update it?

Comment: @meica i found the solution, i Assigned the the button text on form load, but the method was never called, because the form was already loaded

Comment: @styx That's great, I assumed something like that